# How to apply math functions while filtering (using loc) in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have retrived a value of x as `x = 10.64589195722904` which I need to match in my existing dataframe using loc. As subtraction result can be a negative value which I must ignore and so I am using math.fabs to achieve it.

```
fdf = df.loc[(math.fabs(df['x'] - x) <= 0.01 & math.fabs(df['x'] - x) >= 0.001)]
```

But this is throwing error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-256-b8a71a5bd17c> in <module>
     10 #     fdf = df.loc[math.fabs((df['x'] - k) <= 0.001) & (math.fabs(df['x'] - k) >= 0.0001) ]
     11 
---> 12 df.loc[(math.fabs(df['x'] - x) <= 0.01 & math.fabs(df['x'] - x) >= 0.001)]
     13 fdf.head()

~\.conda\envs\pyenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in wrapper(self)
    110         if len(self) == 1:
    111             return converter(self.iloc[0])
--> 112         raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")
    113 
    114     wrapper.__name__ = f"__{converter.__name__}__"

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.fabs`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fabs.html) for processing values vectorized way and also add `()` around masks because priority operators:

```
s = np.fabs(df['x'] - x)
fdf = df[(s <= 0.01) & (s >= 0.001)]
```

Alternative is use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
fdf = df[np.fabs(df['x'] - x).between(0.01, 0.001)]
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 1):

- [`math.fabs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.fabs) only takes a single value, so `.apply` can be used to create a new column, and then perform the Boolean selection.
- As [shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64131349) by [`jezrael`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael), `np.fabs` can be used for a vectorized approach

  - The benefit is, numpy is faster

```py
# apply math.fabs and create a column
df['fabs'] = df['x'].apply(lambda row: math.fabs(row) - x)

# filter on the new column
fdf = df[(df['fabs'] <= 0.01) & (df['fabs'] >= 0.001)]
```